# How can I input code stored in a MySQL cell into my Python beautifulsoup

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pymysql

I'm parsing through many different websites and want to keep their unique tags in a MySQL table and use that stored code to retrieve new content through using beautiful soup. However i'm having trouble when retrieving that code and placing it in my beautiful soup for more complicated tags outside of 'title'.

So it works for simple tags such as 'title', but not for 'div', {'class': 'event-info'}, which is row[3] in my example.

**'div',{'class':'event-info'}** is in my mysql cell in row[3]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
    content = soup.find(row[3]).get_text().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

My column is using "varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're calling the `find` method with a string.
In order to have the right behavior you should save the different arguments in separate columns in your MySQL table, or you could change the value like this:

```
rs = row[3].split(',')
rtag = rs[0].split('\'')[1]

rclass = dict()
rclass[rs[1].split('\'')[1]] = rs[1].split('\'')[3]
```

And finally:

```
content = soup.find(rtag, rclass).get_text().strip()
```